# Headphone volume controls Speaker Volume in Acer NE46RS1 Laptop and volume muting problem also

Tags: acer

As my HP ultrabook has it's trackpad needing replacement, I purchased a cheap $198 Acer Gateway NE46RS1 laptop and installed Linux Mint 18 on it. This laptop has only an integrated speaker apart from headphone out.

So, I found out that in alsamixer, it needs "headphone" volume increased so as to get sound from laptop speaker. Also, if I plug inn earphone, the speaker gets muted and it remains so, unless I again increase headphone volume. If I want speaker to work headphone volume must be turned up in mixer. I tried to save alsa state by running 'sudo alsactl store' which is not retaining on next reboot and gets muted. Also, see that "front" volume is missing.
[image: alsamixer: see that headphone controls speaker and headphone volumes]

What I want is to re-assign proper volume control option for speakers instead of using "headphone" volume as well as to save the volume state instead of getting auto-muted on every boot.

Please see the alsamixer controls and alsa-info.sh details:
[Alsa-Info Results](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=fff4cf3cf50991e524c71cc1807d6d9f789c0c3c)

My sound card:

```
cat /proc/asound/cards 
0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                  HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7c10000 irq 30
```

amixer details:

```
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
Playback channels: Mono
Limits: Playback 0 - 87
Mono: Playback 83 [95%] [-3.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0
Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
Limits: Playback 0 - 87
Mono:
Front Left: Playback 82 [94%] [-3.75dB] [off]
Front Right: Playback 82 [94%] [-3.75dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Speaker',0
Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
Limits: Playback 0 - 87
Mono:
Front Left: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Front Right: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
Capabilities: pvolume
Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
Limits: Playback 0 - 255
Mono:
Front Left: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
Front Right: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
Limits: Playback 0 - 31
Mono:
Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Mic Boost',0
Capabilities: volume
Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
Limits: 0 - 3
Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
Playback channels: Mono
Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Beep',0
Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
Limits: Playback 0 - 31
Mono:
Front Left: Playback 4 [13%] [-28.50dB] [off]
Front Right: Playback 4 [13%] [-28.50dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
Limits: Capture 0 - 63
Front Left: Capture 38 [60%] [11.25dB] [on]
Front Right: Capture 38 [60%] [11.25dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Auto-Mute Mode',0
Capabilities: enum
Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
Item0: 'Enabled'
Simple mixer control 'Digital',0
Capabilities: cvolume
Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
Limits: Capture 0 - 120
Front Left: Capture 60 [50%] [0.00dB]
Front Right: Capture 60 [50%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Internal Mic',0
Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
Limits: Playback 0 - 31
Mono:
Front Left: Playback 14 [45%] [-13.50dB] [off]
Front Right: Playback 14 [45%] [-13.50dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Internal Mic Boost',0
Capabilities: volume
Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
Limits: 0 - 3
Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Loopback Mixing',0
Capabilities: enum
Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
Item0: 'Enabled'
```